# nimbus look and feel

Tags: java, swing

Доброе время суток.
Подскажите толковый мануал по nimbus look and feel.
Вопросы:

1. JInternalFrame. Как убрать выпадающие меню, верхнем левом углу.
2. JFileChooser. Как переназначить путь для кнопки Home.